# Eclipse CDT configuaration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have installed eclipse with CDT. I have GNU compiler tool chain installed on my PC. But I need to replace the GNU compiler tool chain with our own Tool chain, how can I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to implement a toolchain definition for CDT is described in the [Managed Build System Extensibility Document](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/guide/mbs/extensibilityGuide/Managed_Build_Extensibility.html). This can be quite a daunting task unless your compiler is very similar to gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *"Help"* > "*Software Updates...*" > "*Add Site...*" > "*Local*" > select the directory of your toolchain.

Now the toolchain will be available for installation on the "Available Software" tab.

Comment: my doubt was regarding how to configure my tools to make a tool chain i.e., we have our own cross compiler, make tools and debugger. And how to integrate this tools in to eclipse